# I updated my Google phone number but it won't update on my YouTube channel

Tags: youtube, google-account, youtube-channel

I want to monetize on my YouTube channel but when I went to monetize, I realized that I had made a mistake by putting my home phone (which can't receive text messages of course) as the phone number on my YouTube channel (Google account). I need to receive a text message to verify for monetization. So I changed my Google account phone number to the cell phone (which is supposed to fix it) but for monetization, Google is still trying to send a text message to my old (home phone) number. Why is this happening?

Comment: Aside: "my home phone (which can't receive text messages _of course_)" - No doubt network dependent, but for some years now we've been able to receive "text" messages on the home/land line. A digital voice reads the text message out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update, YouTube has updated my phone number, I guess it just took about a week for them to do it.